# Django error for Tiwsted: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0

Tags: django, macos, pip, twisted, zope

In Django (on Mac 10.9), I installed Scrapy in a virtualenv using:

pip install Scrapy

But Django fails with:

```
Type: ImportError Exception Value: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later: no module named zope.interface
```

I've tried reinstalling Twsited and zope pip says requirement is satisfied.  Does any one have a solution?

Admittedly I am pretty new to pip, virtualenv and even developing on a Mac so no answer is under appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps try installing zope interface first?

Comment: not a bad idea but do you mean start over and install zope.interface first?  I have tried upgrading all packages involved to no avail . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First - I do not understand the meaning of your last sentence ("Admittedly I am pretty know to pip, virtualenv and even developing on a Mac so no answer is under appreciated!")
I guess my english is insufficient.

I don't know Twisted, nor Django, but...

This could be a missing dependency of Twisted.

Or more likely, you have a too old version of setuptools installed (Which has problems with the dependency resolution.)

So you could try:

- Update setuptools to a recent version (`pip install -U setuptools`).
- Manually install zope.interface >= 3.6.0 (`pip install zope.interface==3.6.0`) - As @shuttle87 mentioned, you have to do this before installing `Scrapy`

Comment: thank you for the heads up.  I did have a serious typo in that sentence!  
But anyway, I tried the first one.  Can you clarify what "Manually" installing means?  Do you mean from source!?!?  SCARY!!

Comment: I updated the answer. I mean you can install zope.interface separately with a specific version.

Comment: I am sorry I neglected to give the check mark here.  Thank you again for your response!